# Distribute Elements of different sizes with a uniform gap between them in After Effects

Tags: alignment, after-effects

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time. Maybe someone has a tip for me. The Problem is also mentioned in the official adobe help, but without a solution.

Adobe Help writes:
"When you distribute layers of different sizes, the spaces between layers may not be uniform. For example, distributing layers by their centers creates equal space between the centers—but different-sized layers extend by different amounts into the space between layers."

Here is a graphic that shows what I want to have in AE. The first and last elements are only half visible.

[image: 1]

Atm i do that in sketch (Distribute Layers horizontally), import it in illustrator and pick the x-values and enter it manual in AE. Thats insane, maybe there is better solution ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to distribute one group of shapes, then distribute all shapes together.

-Create each shape in a separate shape layer.
-Center each anchor point to it's shape.
-Place the first green shape at 0 position, and the last green shape at 1920 position, both in the x axis.
-Select all green shape layers and click Distribute Horizontally.
-Manually place each red shape at the designated gap between two green shapes. It doesn't matter if the spaces are different.
-Select all shapes and click Distribute Horizontally, then click Align Vertically.

I hope i understood you correctly because it's weird no one answered this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a simple but perfect answer.